# Concurrent or sequential?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I'm playing around with Threads in Java.
The following example I found on a website:

```
public class ThreadTest {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
        t1.start();

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Thread2());
        t2.start();
    }

}

public class Thread1 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println(new java.util.Date());
        }
    }

}

public class Thread2 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```

The expected result would be something like:

```
Mon Nov 11 20:06:12 CET 2013
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
Mon Nov 11 20:06:12 CET 2013
10
```

But I get:

```
0
1
2
3
...
19
Mon Nov 11 20:06:12 CET 2013
Mon Nov 11 20:06:12 CET 2013
Mon Nov 11 20:06:12 CET 2013
...
Mon Nov 11 20:06:12 CET 2013
```

So it doesn't seem concurrent but sequential. Is it because of the speed?

Comment: bump up your limit from 20 to 20000, does that change the results?

Comment: Create both Threads and then start them and either sleep or do more iterations!

Comment: @hvgotcodes It has the exact same effect, first the `i` gets printed, then the `Date`

Comment: It's probably worth noting that if creating the thread takes longer than it's execution, then there's really NO reason to use a thread. I understand this is a learning exercise, but this is a little bit of intuition to let you know when you're doing something silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating the second thread takes more time than the first one needs to finish. Do this:

```
public class ThreadTest {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
       Thread t1 = new Thread(new Thread1());
       Thread t2 = new Thread(new Thread2());
       t1.start();
       t2.start();
   }

}

public class Thread1 implements Runnable {

   @Override
   public void run() {
       for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
            System.out.println(new java.util.Date());
        }
    }

}

public class Thread2 implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
           System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```

If in doubt use Integer.MAX_VALUE instead of 200000.

Answer (score 2):

It's because printing 20 dates is much faster than you think, and the first thread has thus completed its task before the first instruction of the second thread has been executed.

Or it's because the scheduler decided to execute all the instructions of thread 1 before letting thread 2 execute its instructions.

Make each thread do much more things, and you'll start seeing the parallelism. Or make them do the same things, but slower, by adding `Thread.sleep()` calls in the loops.